# Customize and change the default UI of pdftron - reactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, pdftron

My question is does pdftron give react native developpers some alternatives to change the whole ui?
As an example, i want to create a bottomTab to control the annotations and other things.
is it possible to do it without touching the java and swift code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your own custom UI and use the set tool API in the PDFTron library. This allows the developer to set what tool mode is currently being used. You can also hide existing toolbars by using the available api’s.
Please see https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-react-native/blob/master/API.md#settoolmode for more information.

Comment: I got the idea thank u so much for ur explanation